# Column not found ERROR in my first CakePHP project

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1054

I'm using CakePHP , and I'm getting the following Error ! 
Which is because

```
ON (`Trip`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`)
```

Should be

```
(`City'.`city_id` = `Trip`.`id`)
```

How Can i Correct that ?

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Trip.city_id' in 'on clause'
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     `Trip`.`id`, `Trip`.`user_id`, `Trip`.`type_id`, `Trip`.`title`,
>     `Trip`.`city1`, `Trip`.`city2`, `Trip`.`date`, `Trip`.`free_places`,
>     `Trip`.`description`, `Trip`.`contact_email`, `Trip`.`created`,
>     `City`.`city_id`, `City`.`city_name`
> FROM
>     `mitfahr-ar`.`trips` AS `Trip`
> LEFT JOIN
>     `mitfahr-ar`.`cities` AS `City` ON (`Trip`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`)
> WHERE 1 = 1
> ```

My Model code is :

```
<?php
class Trip extends AppModel
{
    public $name= 'Trip';
    public $belongsTo= array('City'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [....] Which is because
>
> ```
> ON (`Trip`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`)
> ```
>
> Should be
>
> ```
> (`City'.`city_id` = `Trip`.`id`)
> ```

No, it shouldn't, the latter one makes absolutely no sense, `` `City`.`city_id` `` would indicate a self-join, and in any case a single city could only be associated with a single other record, which makes no sense [**normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) wise.

The former expression generated by CakePHP is absolutely correct, in a `belongsTo` assocaition, the foreign key is held by the current model.

See **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto**

So to fix the problem, add the proper `city_id` foreign key to your `trips` table.

Answer (score 0):

> ON (`Trip`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`)

Above query is because of the way you are associating the models.

Since in your below assocaiton:

```
<?php
class Trip extends AppModel
{
    public $name= 'Trip';
    public $belongsTo= array('City'); 
}
?>
```

you are not defining any foreign key hence according to the conventions of cakephp, it would automatically search for the field 'city_id' field and you have created that, hence the query.

Solution:

You have to define the foreign key attribute in your association.